# Why does Service.providers(java.sql.Driver.class) can always get mysql's driver? p

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm testing Proxool connection pool now (the DB is mysql), and I find a very curious case, which is that the mysql's Driver can always be registered to DriverManager even though I don't explicitly invoke

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

while the Proxool's Driver cann't. And I look into the JDK code and find a clue, which is that

```
Service.providers(java.sql.Driver.class)
```

can get mysql's Driver while cann't get Proxools. This maybe the reason. And my question is why this method can automatically find mysql's driver?

The following is my testing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   Iterator drivers = Service.providers(java.sql.Driver.class);
   while(it.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(it.next());
   }
}
```

and the result is:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@31d520c4
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1f5a3d6b
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is driver class located in JDBC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288058/how-is-driver-class-located-in-jdbc4)

Comment: Proxool is either not JDBC 4 compliant, or explicitly chose not to declare itself in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`