# Confusion in SPI automatic registration of "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

Recently I have been working on a Java Web Application with JDBC and I have found that `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated since "Connector/J API 8.0".

Therefore as shown below, the Java Runtime warns you to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, instead of using the deprecated driver.

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated.
The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'.
The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

What my problem is really lies under this line.

```
The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

At first, I have thought this means it is not required to call `Class.forName` to register the driver, but after testing out, I have found that I was wrong.

So what is actually mean by `manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary`? Is there something that I have missed?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288058/how-is-driver-class-located-in-jdbc4

Comment: Manual loading may still be necessary if the driver is not on the initial classpath, but - for example - on the classpath of a WAR.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry for bothering you, but what do you mean by "classpath of a WAR"?  can you elaborate?

Comment: If you include a driver in the `WEB-INF/lib` of a WAR (instead of having it on the classpath of your application server itself), it will not be automatically loaded and you (or better: your data source implementation) will need to load it explicitly.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It makes sense now. so, the solution is to include the driver in the application server's classpath (for example - `apache-tomcat-9.0.19\lib`), right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL Connector/J developer guide is still referring to the Class.forName. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

But starting with JDBC 4, the Service Provider Interface is used, so the call should no longer be required. (And for me it works without the Class.forName call!)

Details about the SPI:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

Comment: I think that I have did something wrong on importing "Connector/J" library on Java Web Project so that I have to manually load the JDBC Driver. (I am new to Java EE and JDBC 4.0, so that's probably a reason to mess up) Nevertheless, I am making this as the correct answer, 'cause it does work on Java SE applications. Your help is appreciated, thank you.